# Copy Table Cell Value to Another Cell - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple HTML table. I would like to have a button that allows the user to copy the value from an existing cell to another cell, e.g. click the button to copy the value from row 1/column 3 to row 3/column 3.

Here's a simple HTML table:

http://jsfiddle.net/XF9BD/1/
When the user clicks the links to "copy from Recent Activity" it would copy the value from the cell 3 rows up in the same column.

Comment: clone the value from selected into new cell ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then think the easiest approach is to insert a clone the chosen `<tr>` into the table, then to modify the the clone.

HTML :

```
<table id="scores" width="358" border="1">
  <tbody id="recentActivities">
  <tr>
    <td width="104">Recent Activity</td>
    <td width="69">Result</td>
    <td width="163"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title">Activity 1</td>
    <td class="result">100</td>
    <td class="action_status"><button class="copy">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title">Activity 2</td>
    <td class="result">300</td>
    <td class="action_status"><button class="copy">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="copiedActivities"></tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript :

```
var $copiedActivities = $("#copiedActivities");
$("button.copy").on('click', function() {
    var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo($copiedActivities);
    var titleCell = clone.find(".title");
    titleCell.text('Projection' + titleCell.text());
    clone.find(".action_status").empty().text('Copy of Recent Activity');
});
```

See [update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9BD/2/)

Edit :
Or how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XF9BD/3/) for some ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I need the destination row to be showing at all times as the user might enter the value directly without pressing the button to copy it from the previous row, so I can't use the cloning approach. I ended up using this in the destination cell: <td class="action"><button class="copy" onclick="$('#projectmodvalue').val( $('#totalmod').val() )" value="Set Value">Copy from Recent Activity</button></td>

Comment: OK, I understand better now that I have seen the answer but it's better to attach event handlers in javascript, rather than in the HTML. Also, with a little thought you should be able to develop a more elegant "algorithmic" solution - ie. a single handler for all "copy ..." buttons, which will fetch values from 3 rows higher, without needing to give the cells individual IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following in the destination cell as I needed this to be visible at all times and allow the user to manually enter the value if required:

```
<td class="action"><button class="copy" onclick="$('#projectmodvalue').val( $('#totalmod').val() )" value="Set Value">Copy from Recent Activity</button></td>
```